# cat: /dev/dsp: Input/output error

Tags: linux

пытаюсь записать звук.

```
cat /dev/dsp >> test.wav
cat: /dev/dsp: Input/output error
```

мне нужно именно `dsp`, потому что это используется в одной программе. но если есть другое устройство, вы тоже скажите. kubuntu 20.04

Comment: а в Вашей системе запись звука вообще работает? Это устройство имеет правильные права доступа?

Comment: @KoVadim да наверное работает. я почитал короче в программе одной документацию. там сказано что dsp уже давно устаревшее. так что по другому надо получить доступ к микрофону.

Comment: Есть обертка, которая эмулирует dsp на альсу.